# Three.js : using SetTimeOut to animate position of a light spawned on scene 5 seconds after startup

Tags: three.js, settimeout

I succeed to spawn a light on my scene after a delay using SetTimeOut. This is working very great.
But in my case, I would like to add animation properties to this light. How can I do this ? If I write animation properties for an element that doesn't exist, three.js is crashing on launch. If I write a SetTimeOut property (like I did for my light in my scene), I'm getting this error on the browser console : "light2 is not defined".

Here is an example :

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.set( 0, 0, 10);

var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 100 );
light.position.set( -150, 0, 15 );
scene.add( light );
      
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1.5, 1.5, 1.5 );
var material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );
   
   
setTimeout(function() {
var light2 = new THREE.PointLight( "hsl(358, 100%, 45%)", 1, 100 );
light2.position.set( 0, 0, 15 );
scene.add( light2 );
}, 5000);   
 
var animate = function () {
 
requestAnimationFrame( animate );

cube.rotation.x += 0.05;
cube.rotation.y += 0.05;
    
light.position.x += 0.5;
 
setTimeout(function() {
  light2.position.x += 0.5;
}, 5001);
 
renderer.render(scene, camera);
 
};
 
animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/100/three.min.js"></script>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
</style>
</head>

<body>
</body>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `var light2;` in outer scope:

```js
var light2;         
setTimeout(function() {
    light2 = new THREE.PointLight( "hsl(358, 100%, 45%)", 1, 100 );
    light2.position.set( 0, 0, 15 );
    scene.add( light2 );
}, 5000);
```

and then check if it is set before using it:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    if (light2) {
        light2.position.x += 0.5;
    }
}, 5001);
```